# Cross Browser Scrollbar customization

Tags: html, css, browser, webkit, mozilla

I want to have my scroll bar color changed, I read couple of example online. But they relate to webkit browsers, and that doesn't work in -moz browser. I found a jquery plugin for all browsers called 'jquery custom scrollbar', but it got 3-4 external files, which i don't want. I need to load it in my one html page, so it work the same across same browser. 
So, my div.container is containing data, i want it scroll (track) to be grey color. How can i do it across all latest browsers?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: You can't.

Long(ish) answer: Browsers and operating systems all have different implementations, and some just don't support theming the scroll bar. You could create custom scrollbars with a library like this though: http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/

Comment: yes, i saw the jscrollpane. Only problem is. it doesn't have CDN for it files, as i just want everything is one file. (client requirement)